# Jsdom how to scrape information from website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jsdom

I'm trying to grab information from this [site](http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/Dep_Detalhe.asp?id=5830756) and add it to a json, but I don't know exactly how (I tried many tutorials none of then with success).

> The information i want is:
>
> Nome civil: ---
>
> Aniversário: ---
>
> Partido/UF: ---
>
> Telefone: ---
>
> Fax: ---
>
> Legislaturas: ---

My Code:

```
function dataDep(arrayDep) {

var urlFormatted = "http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/" + arrayDep;

jsdom.env({

     url: urlFormatted,
     scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
     done: function(errors, window) {
        var $s = window.$;
        var depObj = {};
         $s('a').each(function() {
            //console.log(window);
            //console.log($s("title").text());
             //console.log($s(this).attr('a'));


         //});
        // var content = $(".documentFirstHeading");
        // console.log(content);
     }
 });


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use cheerio and request modules for load and parse page data
Cheerio works like jQuery but in backend

You may have some problems like the page in your post dont have class or ids for identify data.

But i found one API how may be good for you: http://www2.camara.leg.br/transparencia/dados-abertos/dados-abertos-legislativo

Comment: And i not found one lib in javascript for connect with camara api in node.js them may be good if you share your code ...